# Optimising Searching of a 2-dimensional Array with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, search

I have a 2-dimensional array of objects (predominantly, but not exclusively strings) that I want to filter by a string (`sSearch`) using LINQ. The following query works, but isn't as fast as I would like.

I have changed `Count` to `Any`, which led to a significant increase in speed and replaced `Contains` by a regular expression that ignores case, thereby elimiating the call to `ToLower`. Combined this has more than halved the execution time.

What is now very noticeable is that increasing the length of the search term from 1 to 2 letters triples the execution time and there is another jump from 3 to 4 letters (~50% increase in execution time). While this is obviously not surprising I wonder whether there is anything else that could be done to optimise the matching of strings?

```
Regex rSearch = new Regex(sSearch, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
rawData.Where(row => row.Any(column => rSearch.IsMatch(column.ToString())));
```

In this case the dataset has about 10k rows and 50 columns, but the size could vary fairly significantly.

Any suggestions on how to optimise this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: They *say* Uppercase comparison is optimized...

Comment: Could you tell us more about your problem (the nature of your data, pattern in sSearch...) ?
I think we have too few elements to go deeper into optimization...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One optimisation is to use `Any` instead of `Count` - that way as soon as one matching column has been found, the row can be returned.

```
rawData.Where(row => row.Any(column => column.ToString()
                                             .ToLower().Contains(sSearch)))
```

You should also be aware that `ToLower` is culture-sensitive. If may not be a problem in your case, but it's worth being aware of. `ToLowerInvariant` *may* be a better option for you. It's a shame there isn't an overload for `Contains` which lets you specify that you want a case-insensitive match...

EDIT: You're using a regular expression now - have you tried `RegexOptions.Compiled`? It may or may not help...

Comment: Great answer, that nearly halved the execution time. I knew there must be something better suited than Count. Any other ideas on how to optimise the updated solution would be great.

Comment: I had tried RegexOptions.Compiled and it had no noticeable effect.

Comment: @Nikolas: Fair enough. It's one of those things that *sometimes* helps and sometimes doesn't.